# How to run multiple jobs in parallel using quartz simplethreadpool, Only one job runs and the other one fails

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have created two jobs, both will generate excel file.I need to generate multiple xlsx in parallel. But one job alone triggers at a time.

```
     <bean id="breakFileXlsxTwo"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="jobClass"
                value="com.citi.recon.quartz.BreakFileXlsxJobTwo" />
            <property name="durability" value="true" />
        </bean>
   <bean id="breakFileXlsxTwoTrigger" 
    class="com.citi.recon.quartz.PersistableCronTriggerFactoryBean">  
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="breakFileXlsxTwo" />  
   <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/10 * * * ?"/>  
    </bean>

    <!-- cluster quartz, will only run in one server -->
    <bean id="clusterquartzScheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">AMLReconQuartzScheduler</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
                </prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">qrtz_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">30</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean class="com.citi.recon.quartz.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                 <ref bean="userSynchJob"/>
                 <ref bean="breakFileDownloadJob"/>
                 <ref bean="breakFileXlsxTwo"/> 

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                 <ref bean="userSynchJobTrigger"/>
                 <ref bean="breakFileDownloadJobTrigger"/>
                 <ref bean="breakFileXlsxTwoTrigger"/>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In both jobs, i have given same 10 mins time interval.

In my job class,i am extending QuartzJobBean like below:

```
public class BreakFileXlsxDownloadJob extends QuartzJobBean
```

Comment: Did you check your logfile for error messages? Could you post them?

Comment: Only its getting logged if the job is succeeded else no log. I am checking its error-ed out from qrtz_trigger table